# pygame.init() fails when run with systemd

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, pygame, systemd

I'm trying to run a python pygame script with systemd and for some reason the script just exits without an error.
This is on a Raspberry Pi with Raspian "Jessie lite".

**If I run the script manually with "sudo python myscript.py" it works fine.**

sudo systemctl status myscript.service reports:

```
* myscript.service - Python Script
Loaded: loaded    /etc/systemd/system/myscript.service; enabled)    Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2016-08-29 04:33:19 UTC; 1s ago
Process: 3275> ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /home/pi/myscript.py (code=killed, signal=HUP)
Main PID: 3275 (code=killed, signal=HUP)
```

If I start the service manually with sudo systemctl start myscript.service the same thing happens.

I've stripped down my script to just the pygame.init() call. This is where it exits.

If I try to initialize the modules manually then "cdrom", "joystick", "threads", and "font" initialize normally but a call to display.init() causes the program to exit. There is no exception raised.

The only resource I could find online is [this guy](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pygame-mirror-on-google-groups/AZcdQfQDMVY). It seems he ran into the exact same thing I'm seeing.
I've tried strace and if I wait long enough (2 minutes), it will work!
Obviously I can't run with strace all the time. I think it slows down the execution of the initialization to somehow allow it to work.

EDIT:
So the issue appears to be systemd sending a SIGHUP. If this is unhandled in Python the default action is to exit. A quick fix is the catch SIGHUP:

```
import signal
def handler(signum, frame):
    pass

try:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)
except AttributeError:
    # Windows compatibility
    pass
```

So many burning questions. Why does systemd do this? Why does strace fix the issue? Why do some Python scripts get SIGHUP while others don't?

Comment: Sounds like a bug or configuration issue. Systemd shouldn't be sending `SIGHUP` unless specified via `SendSIGHUP=` or `KillSignal=` ...

Comment: A possible solution is to disable SIGHUP in systemd but I'm not sure what other effects this could have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55392107/how-to-run-pygame-script-using-systemd-service

Answer (score 2):

I don't have an answer, but I'm experiencing the same thing, so I'll add some more detail.

Here's the cut-down code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import logging
from pygame import display
import signal
import time

def handler(signum, frame):
  """Why is systemd sending sighups? I DON'T KNOW."""
  logging.warning("Got a {} signal. Doing nothing".format(signum))

signal.signal(signal.SIGHUP, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, handler)
signal.signal(signal.SIGCONT, handler)

logging.warning("About to start display.")
try:
  display.init()   # hups
except Exception as ex:
  logging.warning("Got any exception: %s " % ex)

logging.warning("Quitting in 60")
time.sleep(60)
```

Here's the log that produces:

```
Jul  8 22:30:27 beardog systemd[1]: Started PyGame Test.
Jul  8 22:30:27 beardog pygame[17406]: WARNING:root:About to start display.
Jul  8 22:30:27 beardog pygame[17406]: WARNING:root:Got a 1 signal. Doing nothing
Jul  8 22:30:27 beardog pygame[17406]: WARNING:root:Got a 18 signal. Doing nothing
Jul  8 22:30:27 beardog pygame[17406]: WARNING:root:Quitting in 60
```

It's getting a SIGCONT immediately after the SIGHUP, but no SIGTERM. Systemd claims to only ever send a SIGHUP after a SIGTERM, so maybe it's coming from somewhere else? I can't find anything relevant in the pygame code though.

I've turned on systemd debug logging, but it doesn't print anything interesting.

Here's my systemd config.

```
[Unit]
Description=PyGame Test
After=syslog.target network.target network-online.target graphical.target

[Service]
Type=simple
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/code/pygame/
ExecStart=/path/to/code/pygame/why.py
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
LimitNOFILE=10000
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog
SyslogIdentifier=pygame
SendSIGHUP=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I've tried this as Type=forking, oneshot and dbus (although it isn't any of them). I've also tried TimeoutStartSec=20, but no change. Tested on an Ubuntu Xenial laptop and on a Raspberry pi running Raspbian. Both python2.7 and python3. Code works fine when run manually, and seems to work when run under strace in systemd. /o\

Like the OP, I can work around it by catching the SIGHUP, but after this much debugging I'd love to know what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

For me the solution was to only init specific modules which I needed.

In my case instead `pygame.init()` I initialized only `pygame.mixer.init()` and now systemd can start the service.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your logs:

```
journalctl -u myservice.service
```

Adding this to your unit file may improve the logging:

```
StandardOutput=journal+console
```

In some cases if some logging happens just before the service exits, the logs won't get tagged with the the service, so after you run the service, also look at:

```
journalctl
```

For entries just after your service exited.

Also, instead using the `network.target`, try the `network-online.target`.

I presume the app runs OK from the command line by itself. Assuming it works that way and not from systemd, differing environment variables can be an issue.  Add a line to the top of your app to dump all the environment variables and compare that output when run from `systemd` vs the CLI.

Finally, review the docs for [Type=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=). If the default Type= doesn't apply to your case, set this appropriately.

Future questions specific to `systemd` may be better answered at the [Unix & Linux StackExchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) as they don't directly relate to programming.

You should also post your `systemd` unit file since that's what you are having trouble with.

Comment: My Python script is writing its own logfile so I know it is executing and how far it is getting. I don't think it is a systemd configuration issue. Good idea about the environment variables. I matched the environment in systemd with the "Environment=" tags, getting it exactly the same as when it is run at the command line but it didn't help.