# How to Run pygame script using systemd service?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, raspberry-pi3, systemd

I Wanted to run pygame script using systemd service for that
followed these steps to run a pygame script using systemd service

`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

`sudo systemctl enable service_name`

`sudo systemctl start service_name`

and rebooted the system after that my-service don't want to run a pygame script for more understading

`$ sudo journalctl -f -u rpi
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-11-03 22:46:42 IST. --
Mar 28 12:19:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started RPi-Service.`

`$sudo systemctl status rpi
  rpi.service - RPi-Service
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rpi.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Thu 2019-03-28 12:19:14 IST; 22min ago
  Process: 689 ExecStart=/home/pi/Documents/project1/allnewone (code=killed, signal=HUP)
 Main PID: 689 (code=killed, signal=HUP)`

**My Service File**

```
#rpi.service
[Unit]
Description= RPi-Service
After = multi-user.target

[Service]
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3  /home/pi/Documents/project1/allnewone.py
Restart = on-abort
RestartSec = 5
KillMode = process
SendSIGHUP = no


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I got answer but now I'm not able to decide should I delete this question or not. This may help other

Comment: if you found a solution feel free to post the answer. You can even accept your own answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the solution

---

```
#rpi.service 
[Unit]
Description= RPi-Service
After = multi-user.target

[Service]
Type = simple
Environment="DISPLAY=:0"
Environment="XAUTHORITY=/home/pi/.Xauthority"
ExecStart = /usr/bin/python3  /home/pi/Documents/project1/allnewone.py
Restart = always
RestartSec = 5
KillMode = process
SendSIGHUP = no


[Install]
WantedBy= graphical.target
```

Comment: Infact this solutions woks on whenever you want to use graphics_uI and run as systemd or may for corn job